# Symfony security access_control allow if NOT having specific role

Tags: symfony, symfony-security, symfony5

In a Symfony 5.0 application I want to define an `access_control` pattern for a route that allows users access that

- **have** the role **ROLE_USER**
- **DO NOT have** the role **ROLE_ADMIN**

So I need something like

```
- { path: ^/xy, roles: [ROLE_USER, not ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

In older Symfony 3.x I used to do it that way:

```
{ path: ^/xy, allow_if: "has_role('ROLE_USER') and not has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')" }
```

But that doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
is_granted()
```

instead of

```
has_role()
```

now.
So this works:

```
- { path: ^/xy, allow_if: "is_granted('ROLE_USER') and not is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" }
```